# How to set "One_Time_Use" parameter of Branch.io link in dash board?

Tags: branch.io

I try to use Branch.io link to download app from App Store and pass some parameters that I can use when app opened for the first time. I need this link to expire after it has been clicked once.

[Do Branch Links Expires?](https://support.branch.io/support/solutions/articles/6000039874-do-branch-links-expire-)
From the link here it recommends me to set "type" to 1 to make the link can only be used once. It doesn't seem to work to me, I tried to press the link and download, install it, check the params. Then delete it and try again. The params stay the same:

```
{
    "$marketing_title" = momtest2;
    "$one_time_use" = 0;
    "+click_timestamp" = 1488349123;
    "+clicked_branch_link" = 1;
    "+is_first_session" = 0;
    "+match_guaranteed" = 1;
    type = 1;
    "~campaign" = Test1;
    "~channel" = "Test_mom365";
    "~creation_source" = 1;
    "~feature" = marketing;
    "~id" = 365368829452660244;
    "~marketing" = 1;
    "~referring_link" = "https://tinybeans.app.link/U925vixy9A";
}
```

I also tried to put "~" or "$" in front of it, it still doesn't make any difference.

1, What's the right way to implement this?
2, Branch.io says it will become "One Time Use" link and expire after it's been used once. Then what does it look like to be expired? is it that no parameters fetched or some particular parameter set to 1 or 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the documentation indicates that "type" can be set to control "one_time_use," use $one_time_use instead. "Type" may still work, but is difficult to set and test and the future is $one_time_use.

The current behavior is as follows: if you set $one_time_use on a link to "true" or 1, the behavior after triggering will be one of the following:

- If after tapping the Branch link the app is opened via Android's App Links or iOS's Universal Links, then all link data will be returned to the SDK, with an additional "$one_time_use_used" parameter that is set to 1
- If after tapping the Branch link the app is opened via redirection (so via URI Scheme or launching the app manually), no link data will be returned and +clicked_branch_link will be 0.

As this behavior is inconsistent, there is a ticket open to resolve the inconsistency and ensure that no data is returned from expired links. There is not currently an ETA on this fix being rolled into production.

Though it is possible to set $one_time_use when creating links via the SDKs or when creating links using query parameters, it is not possible to set $one_time_use via the dashboard.

To create a basic new link with $one_time_use set, append the key value pair as a parameter after the app's link domain. The following link, for example, will create a new $one_time_use Branch link (to which you could, of course, append other key-value pairs):

https://testbed-swift.app.link?$one_time_use=1&token=sampletoken

Note that the above link will instantiate a new Branch link each time it is tapped, so this isn't all that useful (to create a link you need to tap on the above link - which is the one time use!).

Comment: I tried to use $one_time_use in DeepLinking tab in Configure Options in Dashboard, but it says "Sorry, $one_time_use cannot be used", so I thought I have to do it by any other ways and this is why I posted this question, any suggestions?

Comment: I've updated the answer above with additional clarification. Unfortunately, you cannot create one_time_use links via the dashboard at the present time.